# How to make a function order some values in a matrix in R?

Tags: r

Trying to write a function to sort a matrix by rows. 
I could write something to loop over the values on a vector of values but couldn't add complexity to make it loop over some matrix.

```
sww = function(x){
  n <- length(x)

      for(i in 1:(n-1)){

         for (j in (i+1):n) {

        if(x[i] > x[j]){
          tmp = x[i]; x[i] = x[j]; x[j] = tmp
          }


        }

      }
  return(x)
}
```

does anyone knows how to make it loop over an entire matrix ?

Edit:

By sorting a matrix by rows I meant to have a matrix like:

```
2 1 4    "Sorted by row"     1 2 4
5 4 0          -->           0 4 5
```

Thank you

Edit1: I know about the r functions but would like to write my own

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Is this a homework to implement bubble sort in R or why don't you use R's `sort` or `order` function? What exactly is meant with "sort a matrix by rows"?

Comment: added an edit about what I meant by sort b rows. Sorry for the confusion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
m <- matrix(c(2, 5, 1, 4, 4, 0), 2) # test matrix
t(apply(m, 1, sort))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    2    4
## [2,]    0    4    5
```

If you really want to loop over the rows:

```
mm <- m
for(i in 1:nrow(m)) mm[i, ] <- sort(m[i, ])
```

and, of course, you can replace `sort` with your own version if you wish.

Comment: I know about that function but was trying to write something by myself to achieve the same

Comment: I just done that by replacing sort by my function sww renamed sortt ```for(i in 1:nrow(m)) mm[i, ] <- sortt(m[i, ])```